# Repeated error message in PfSense

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

My PfSense box is constantly writing this message in the error log every few seconds. I think this is a sound card related error but have found no solution to fix this. All packages in PfSense are up to date.

```
hdac0: Unexpected unsolicited response from address 0: 00000000
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6BvR.png)

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: if you think its the sound card, disable it in the bios, or if its in ATX form remove the card. let me know if it resolves it.